# Sqlite Foreign key mismatch sequelize migration

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

My request SQL fail when I try to insert data in my table `PostVotes`
I use sequelize migration to migrate my database  and I have the same probleme when I make my sql request in my console.

`sequelize db:migrate`

When I use `sequelize.sync()` i don't have this problem

My table:

```
/* TABLE Users */
  queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
  }),
  queryInterface.createTable('Posts', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    },
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    userId: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      references: {
        model: 'Users',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  }),

  /* Table posts votes*/
  queryInterface.createTable('PostVotes', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    },
    vote: {
      // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
      type: Sequelize.ENUM('up', 'down'),
      validate: {
        isIn: [['up', 'down']],
      },
      allowNull: false,
    },
    userId: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      references: {
        model: 'Users',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
    postId: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      references: {
        model: 'Posts',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  }),
```

> [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: foreign key mismatch - "PostVotes" referencing "Posts"]

I already find answer but nothing is working. I think my mistake is in the table PostVotes but I don't understand what.

Thanks !

Comment: It looks like the issue is all of those primaryKey: true properties in the objects that refer to foreign keys. Keep the primaryKey properties on the "id" columns, but remove them from things like postId and userId.

Answer (score 0):

FIX

```
queryInterface.createTable('Posts', {
id: {
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  type: Sequelize.UUID,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
},
title: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
},
userId: {
  type: Sequelize.UUID,
  primaryKey: true, # DELETE THIS ONE
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  references: {
    model: 'Users',
    key: 'id',
  },
},
```

}),

I delete primaryKey in table Post column userId

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.